# When will the Edge Chromium WebView control (WebView2) be public (i.e. come out of developer preview)?

Tags: webview, microsoft-edge, chromium, webviewchromium

We've committed to using Edge-Chromium and the new WebView2 control.

Any update on the when it will become generally available?  (Currently it is "developer preview")  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2

Answer (score 0):

At present, we don't have any information when WebView2 will available generally, you could keep visiting [the Microsoft Edge WebView2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/hosting/webview2) page. If it is public, we will update the document status as soon as possible. Thanks for your understanding.